# Configuring Sequelize with Azure SQL DB (express/node)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm prety new to nodejs and even more so Sequelize.  I'm trying to setup an API to MSSQL using Sequelize but some of the basics are eluding me.  I just can't seem to interact with my SQL DB.

This is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var models = require('./models');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3011;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var transactionRouter = require('./server/Routes/transactionRoutes')();
var userRouter = require('./server/Routes/userRoutes')();
var authRouter = require('./server/Routes/authRoutes')();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8012');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.use('/api/transactions', transactionRouter);
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('welcome to my API');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Gulp is running my app on PORT: ' + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Models/Index.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword', {
    host: 'dbhostname',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

var db = {};

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

A model Models/user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('BO_Users', {
    username        : DataTypes.STRING,
    password     : DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  return User;
};
```

A the routes server/Routes/userRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var models  = require('../../models');


var routes = function() {
    var userRouter = express.Router();

    userRouter.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            console.log("Made it to the new route");
            console.log("made it to the new get route");
            models.User.findAll({})
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Got some users');
            });
        })
        .post(function(req, res) {
            console.log("Made it to the post route");
        });

    return userRouter;
};

module.exports = routes;
```

I'm pretty sure I need to do a models.sequelize.sync() somewhere, but I'm kinda lost and having trouble finding a good tutorial that gets through to me.  I have the tables in place, I just want to start interacting with them.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, I would suggest putting the .sync() in server.js just prior to and wrapping the listener so that the app cannot be interacted with before the DB is ready.

For example:

```
models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    console.log('starting listener on PORT: '+port);
    app.listen(port, function(err) {
        if(err) return console.error('Failed to start listener: '+err);
        console.log('Gulp is running my app on PORT: ' + port);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.error('failed to sync DB: '+err);
});
```

Comment: I had a variation of that initially, but it seemed to prevent the site from starting up.  Unfortunately, it's doesn't seem to return any helpful info that I'm aware of.  This is what my console looks like:   

    [23:22:19] Starting 'default'...
    [23:22:19] Finished 'default' after 1.6 ms
    [23:22:19] [nodemon] 1.9.1
    [23:22:19] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [23:22:19] [nodemon] watching: *.*
    [23:22:19] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
    File:  account.js
    File:  user.js
    [23:22:51] [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Comment: @EricBarb - sorry missed the fact that you had not created a HTTP listener.  I'll update the answer

Comment: @EricBarb - sorry jumped to conclusions - you code should work without creating a HTTP server.  I would output what 'port' is prior to the app.listener call

Comment: I pasted in the updated code above but still having the same results.  I appreciate your time thus far.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi @EricBarb - I tried the code you posted and it works for me, so I suspect there is something going on in the other code you have not posted.  Did the code I suggested actually run? i.e. did it output the port number or fail to even reach it?

Comment: It did not output the port number.  I was able to access the same DB in question using the MSSQL node module.  So I think it's at least safe to assume I'm using the right settings (ie Username, Password, Host) and not having a firewall issue.   I'll keep playing around with it now that I know it should work.

Comment: I think I found something.  For Azure, I needed to use encrypt in my dialectOptions, I had SSL.
  dialectOptions: {
        encrypt: true
  }

I'm already getting better results.  Errors, but results :-)

Comment: THANK YOU!  I really appreciate you helping me through this.  Case closed.